# Fastest way to play a sound in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, audio

What is the fastest way to play a sound in the browser? I have a Javascript script here that is being run through Chrome on an Android tablet (XO Tablet). I'd like it to make a "click" sound every time the user taps on the screen. The tapping is being registered extremely fast (as fast as I can tap), but the sound file that is being played can't keep up and only plays about once ever 5 or 6 taps.

I am using HTML5 and followed the directions on this site: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/soundlink.shtml#current

Is there a way that will play sounds faster? Or in other words, that uses less resources such that it can be played over and over very very quickly?

Answer (score 0):

use the audio tag from HTML5

jquery:

```
$('menu li').bind('touchstart mousedown click', function(e){
   $('audio')[0].play();
});
```

the markup:

```
<audio hidden>
       <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
       <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
       Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<menu type="list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</menu>
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a8JYc/

Comment: This works fine in the browser (as does the way I am already using), but does not work on the Tablet I mentioned in the question (whereas the code I am using does work on the tablet, it is just too slow)